# Inserting developerPayload to getBuyIntent() method

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I try to make Google Play Billing Service via `com.android.billingclient:billing-dp1` library. I try starting the billing process by calling:

```
billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, params);
```

So the question is how to pass "developerPayload" argument to this flow? Both `launchBillingFlow` and it's `params` argument don't contain such a field.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I opened an issue on the developers' page and they answered the following:

---

*I just discovered that `developerPayload` doesn't always work. In several instances, for example when using a promo code, a later call to getPurchases() will not include the information that was sent. This limitation makes `developerPayload` useless. Google's official stance is that it should NOT be used for security purposes even though a bunch of documentation and the official Trivial Drive example say otherwise. Hope this saves you some time.*

---

See details [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/67)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, if you look at the sources of `BillingClientImpl` you'll see this:

```
buyIntentBundle =
        mService.getBuyIntent(3, mContext.getPackageName(), newSku, skuType, null);
```

The Last `null` is the `developerPayload`:

```
Bundle getBuyIntent(int apiVersion, String packageName, String sku, String type,
    String developerPayload);
```

So, no implementation for `developerPayload` yet.

Comment: Oh... What would you suggest to do? Direct subclassing is not possible :( maybe rewrite a library?

Answer (score 0):

Is the InitiatePurchase command used in billing?  Because you pass the developerPayload in the InitiatePurchase command...

```
string developerPayload = "the info you are passing in the developerPayload";   
m_storeController.InitiatePurchase (product, developerPayload);
```

That's it.

Comment: Do you really mean `com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1` library? If yes, could you please provide us with more detailed sample with `BillingClient` instance?